# Inputting an Array value in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I have googled and can not work out what I am doing wrong.

I have the below function that I am trying to use Remix to manually input the fields.

"function testForward(bytes calldata info, uint[4][] calldata guardians) external"

I can not for the life of me, work out how to get the array entered correctly. Every time i try to transact i get an error. Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value.

I have tried so many different combos with "" & [] but can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and figured out how the inputs should be provided. You just need to send a variable array of arrays containing exactly 4 elements. For example,

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

I am not sure if this is what you want to do with this piece of code, but the inputs will work like that.

Comment: I owe you a beer! Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha. I am looking forward to it. :)